# Cant create a file and write to it from a .sh script

Tags: bash, filesystem, files, scripts

I am trying to create a file and write to it using a `.sh` script but is not working(Nothing is being created, and I don't see any error).

This is how that part of my script looks like:

```
facesConfigContent="<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<faces-config version=\"2.2\"
              xmlns=\"http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee\"
              xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"
              xsi:schemaLocation=\"http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd\">
</faces-config>"
facesConfigFileName="faces-config.xml"
cd ~/Desktop/${artifactId}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF
echo ${facesConfigContent} > ${facesConfigFileName}
```

Do you see something wrong?

Comment: You are using multiple quotes, so my guess is either with the multiple quotes or 'cd ~/Desktop/${artifactId}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF" is also ambiguous. You should use the full path in scripts. You should probably use a "here-doc" http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html or read the doc from a file (source it)

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I scaped them correctly. Do you think they are wrong?

Comment: The quotes are fine.  Are you even using bash, because the ~ will not be known in sh.  Follow above suggestion to use full path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What exactly is $artifactId ?? If I try to run your code by modifying it like this, it work perfectly fine, so there must be some problem in your cd command

```
facesConfigContent="<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<faces-config version=\"2.2\"
          xmlns=\"http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee\"
          xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"
          xsi:schemaLocation=\"http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd\">
</faces-config>"
facesConfigFileName="faces-config.xml"
cd ~/Desktop/
echo ${facesConfigContent} > ${facesConfigFileName}
```

Comment: `${artifactId}` is just a variable that came from a `read` command. Thanks for the answer